# Creating a running count in R based on Dates

Tags: r, count

I am trying to create a running count in R based on Dates and getting a bit confused.

What I have is:

DF1

| ID | Date | Inv | Inved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-01 | 0 | 0 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-02 | 9 | 9 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-03 | 0 | 0 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-04 | 15 | 0 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-05 | 0 | 0 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-06 | 7 | 4 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-07 | 0 | 0 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-08 | 0 | 5 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-09 | 12 | 0 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-11 | 18 | 0 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-12 | 0 | 0 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-13 | 12 | 10 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-14 | 18 | 0 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-15 | 0 | 5 |

I want a running count of Inv. If there are 9 reports Invoicing1 on Day1 and that same day 9 are Invoiced1. Then on Day 2, Invoicing 1 should = 0. Any help on the equation used to get to the calculation below would be appreciated.

What I want is:
DF2

| ID | Date | Inv | Inved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-01 | 0 | 0 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-02 | 9 | 9 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-03 | 0 | 9 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-04 | 15 | 9 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-05 | 15 | 9 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-06 | 18 | 13 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-07 | 18 | 13 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-08 | 13 | 18 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-09 | 25 | 18 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-11 | 43 | 18 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-12 | 43 | 18 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-13 | 45 | 28 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-14 | 63 | 28 |
| XYZ1 | 2021-04-15 | 58 | 33 |

Here is a reproducible sample of the data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c('XYZ1','XYZ1', 'XYZ1', 'XYZ1', 'XYZ1', 'XYZ1', 'XYZ1', 'XYZ1', 'XYZ1','XYZ1', 'XYZ1', 'XYZ1', 'XYZ1','XYZ1'),
                  Date = c(2021-04-01, 2021-04-02, 2021-04-03, 2021-04-04, 2021-04-05, 2021-04-06, 2021-04-07, 2021-04-08, 2021-04-09, 2021-04-10, 2021-04-11, 2021-04-12, 2021-04-13, 2021-04-14),
                  Inv = c(0,9,0,15,0,7,0,0,12,18,0,12,18,0),
                  Inved = c(0,9,0,0,0,4,0,5,0,0,0,10,0,5))
```

What I would like to create the calculations required to go from DF1 to DF2.

I would essentially like to figure out how to write the equation to go from DF1 to DF2.

What I believe is happening is:

1: Inv is subtracted by Inved. DF1$Row3 = DF1$Row3Inv = DF1$Row3Inved.

2: In Row 3, Inv is now 0 as the Invoicing have been transfered to Invoiced.

3: If Inv continues to grow as Inved doesn't change then Inv needs to be added up.

4: As Inv grows, if there is a increased in Inved then that must be subtracted

Comment: Would you pls clarify your required

Comment: @MohamedDesouky I have edited to add more information. Please let me know if you might know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try but with only number changed in the second row

```
df1$Inv <- cumsum(df1$Inv - df1$Inved)

df1$Inved <- cumsum(df1$Inved)
```